# Is it safe to keep a reference to Android application context?

Tags: android, android-context, lifecycle

In an Android app is it safe to keep a reference to the application context returned from `Context.getApplicationContext()` throughout the lifetime of the app?

```
Context ac = context.getApplicationContext();
// keep the ac reference throughout the app lifetime
```

Comment: Have a look at this http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. The application context wont change until the app gets killed by the system.And when the app gets killed, your variables get cleared. 
On the other hand, its unsafe to persist activity context.